# PyQT6: Preventing superposition of items during Drop Event

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt6

I have designed a GUI in PyQT6 allowing the user to drag & drop items between 2 widgets. The issue I am facing is that an item can superpose onto another at the destination during the drop event. Ideally, I would like to shift existing items at/below the destination downwards (by 1 row) in order to make room for the new item.

This is my current code block:

```
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QListView, QAbstractItemView, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QLabel
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt, QSize
from PyQt6.QtGui import QStandardItemModel, QIcon, QStandardItem



class Draggable_ListView(QListView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.setIconSize(QSize(150, 150))
        self.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.DragDropMode.DragDrop)
        self.setResizeMode(QListView.ResizeMode.Adjust)
        self.setViewMode(QListView.ViewMode.ListMode)

    
    def dropEvent(self, event):     
        super().dropEvent(event) 
        event.setDropAction(Qt.DropAction.MoveAction)


class ListView_Left(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.subtitle = 'List 1'

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        # Add a QLabel for the subtitle
        subtitle_label = QLabel(self.subtitle)
        layout.addWidget(subtitle_label, alignment=Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)

        self.list_view = Draggable_ListView(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.list_view)

    def set_model(self, model):
        self.list_view.setModel(model)

    def get_model(self):
        return self.list_view.model()

class ListView_Right(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.subtitle = 'List 2'

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        # Add a QLabel for the subtitle
        subtitle_label = QLabel(self.subtitle)
        layout.addWidget(subtitle_label, alignment=Qt.AlignmentFlag.AlignCenter)

        self.list_view = Draggable_ListView(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.list_view)

    def set_model(self, model):
        self.list_view.setModel(model)

    def get_model(self):
        return self.list_view.model()



class MyApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.window_width, self.window_height = 1400, 500
        self.setMinimumSize(self.window_width, self.window_height)
        self.resize(self.window_width, self.window_height)

        layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.listViewLeft = ListView_Left(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.listViewLeft)

        self.listViewRight = ListView_Right(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.listViewRight)

        icon = QStandardItem()
        icon.setIcon(QIcon(r"path to JPG image"))
        icon_2 = QStandardItem()
        icon_2.setIcon(QIcon(r"path to JPG image_1"))
        icon_3 = QStandardItem()
        icon_3.setIcon(QIcon(r"path to JPG image_2"))

        
        self.listViewLeft.set_model(QStandardItemModel(self))
        self.listViewLeft.get_model().appendRow(icon)
        self.listViewLeft.get_model().appendRow(icon_2)
        self.listViewLeft.get_model().appendRow(icon_3)

        self.listViewRight.set_model(QStandardItemModel(self))



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    
    myApp = MyApp()
    myApp.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

What I have tried was to count how many items (rows) were already at the destination and compare this count with the index of the row I am planning to drop my new item. From there, I would insert a new row, shifting current rows at/below the destination downwards. However, I realized that the row at which my new item is to be inserted is generated only after the new item has been dropped. So, I was wondering if there was a different approach or any in-built attribute I could use.

Comment: `icon.setFlags(icon.flags() & ~Qt.ItemIsDropEnabled)`, and the same for all the other items.

Comment: @musicamante. Yes. The syntax is a bit off but the following works for me: icon.setFlags(icon.flags() & ~Qt.ItemFlag.ItemIsDropEnabled). Thank you so much